# How to play KBounce?

Tags: kbounce

I read [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KBounce) about it, but what I want to know is how to play it in the first place.

[image]

**How do I draw walls? How do I stop them? How do I control them?**

thanks!

Comment: Do you see in the screenshot the pull-down menu labelled "Help"?  Did you try opening it?  Did you see the entry "KBounce Handbook" that opens to a table contents with a section called "How To Play"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use the mouse to create walls (click where you want them placed, right click to swap between horizontal wall building and vertical wall building).

   - If an unfinished wall is hit by a ball, you lose a life and the wall section stops growing.
     This is the *only* way to "stop" walls.
2. Use walls to section the board in "rooms".
3. If a room is closed and does not contain a ball, it counts as "filled". Walls also count as filled.
4. Fill enough of the board to move to the next level (with more balls).

Here, have a commented screenshot of [the original game](http://www.jezzball.org/).

[image: Jezzball screenshot]

If you really have too much time on your hands, [this how-to](http://www.wikihow.com/Win-at-Kbounce) explains how to exploit the game "physics" to complete levels of any difficulty.

Answer (score 3):

Your goal is to fill 75% of the board.

If you create a closed line (i.e. a square) with no balls in it then it gets filled. You can build vertical and horizontal walls (right click to choose wall direction), the wall will be built starting at your mouse position and propagates from that point in two direction, suppose you're building an horizontal wall then it will propagate on the right and on the left.

You have to be careful because wall-building gets interrupted by balls' collision, and that's the game.

In some versions if a ball hits a head of a propagating wall the wall stops to grow and the ball bounce, if a ball hits a side of a propagating wall it destroy that wall and you lose a life.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a video on You tube on how you can play this game.

Comment: thanks axrwkr for editing it, I haven't figured out yesterday how to do it, I was looking for video link but I didn't find.  Thanks again.